# Round two corners in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, rounded-corners

A little while ago I posted a question about [rounding just two corners of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845211/just-two-rounded-corners), and got a great response, but am having problems implementing it. Here is my drawRect: method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    //[super drawRect:rect]; <------Should I uncomment this?
    int radius = 5;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddArc(context, rect.origin.x + radius, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - radius, radius, M_PI, M_PI / 2, 1);
    CGContextAddArc(context, rect.origin.x + rect.size.width - radius, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - radius, radius, M_PI / 2, 0.0f, 1);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextClip(context);
}
```

The method is being called, but doesn't seem to affect the outcome of the view. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

[CACornerMask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cacornermask?utm_source=Little%20Bites%20of%20Cocoa&utm_campaign=5e8e3ea5c8-EMAIL_CAMPAIGN_2017_06_16&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_2b6df83b4b-5e8e3ea5c8-114264253) introduced in iOS 11, which help to define topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottom right in view layer. Below is example to use.

Here I try to rounded only two top corner:

```
myView.clipsToBounds = true
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
myView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner,.layerMaxXMinYCorner]
```

FYI Ref:

[image]

Comment: This looks like the idiomatic way to do this now. Good catch!

Comment: Note the view's width/height still needs to be at least twice the corner radius, or strange artifacts appear. e.g. rounding only the bottom corners, a radius of 20 and height of only 30 results in a visibly narrower cell (by a pixel or two).

Comment: Note that this is the correct way if your view changes its frame (possible due to an expanding UITextView, as in my case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50926215/uiview-background-color-not-redrawn-when-frame-changes-in-dynamically-expanding ).

If you set a UIBezierPath, it won't update automatically when the frame changes.

Comment: Noted it's only available from iOS 11 and above `if #available(iOS 11.0, *) { }`

Comment: Great answer. Turns out setting `clipsToBounds` to `true` is not necessary. You can mask corners and add shadow to the layer when `clipsToBounds` is `false`. Came in handy for me.

Comment: Perfect! Works for me

Answer (score 72):

as far as I know, if you also need to mask the subviews, you could use `CALayer` masking. There are 2 ways to do this. The first one is a bit more elegant, the second one is a workaround :-) but it's also fast. Both are based on `CALayer` masking. I've used both methods in a couple of projects last year then I hope you can find something useful.

#### Solution 1

First of all, I created this function to generate an image mask on the fly (`UIImage`) with the rounded corner I need. This function essentially needs 5 parameters: the bounds of the image and 4 corner radius (top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right).

```
static inline UIImage* MTDContextCreateRoundedMask( CGRect rect, CGFloat radius_tl, CGFloat radius_tr, CGFloat radius_bl, CGFloat radius_br ) {  

    CGContextRef context;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // create a bitmap graphics context the size of the image
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate( NULL, rect.size.width, rect.size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast );

    // free the rgb colorspace
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);    

    if ( context == NULL ) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // cerate mask

    CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX( rect ), midx = CGRectGetMidX( rect ), maxx = CGRectGetMaxX( rect );
    CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY( rect ), midy = CGRectGetMidY( rect ), maxy = CGRectGetMaxY( rect );

    CGContextBeginPath( context );
    CGContextSetGrayFillColor( context, 1.0, 0.0 );
    CGContextAddRect( context, rect );
    CGContextClosePath( context );
    CGContextDrawPath( context, kCGPathFill );

    CGContextSetGrayFillColor( context, 1.0, 1.0 );
    CGContextBeginPath( context );
    CGContextMoveToPoint( context, minx, midy );
    CGContextAddArcToPoint( context, minx, miny, midx, miny, radius_bl );
    CGContextAddArcToPoint( context, maxx, miny, maxx, midy, radius_br );
    CGContextAddArcToPoint( context, maxx, maxy, midx, maxy, radius_tr );
    CGContextAddArcToPoint( context, minx, maxy, minx, midy, radius_tl );
    CGContextClosePath( context );
    CGContextDrawPath( context, kCGPathFill );

    // Create CGImageRef of the main view bitmap content, and then
    // release that bitmap context
    CGImageRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreateImage( context );
    CGContextRelease( context );

    // convert the finished resized image to a UIImage 
    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:bitmapContext];
    // image is retained by the property setting above, so we can 
    // release the original
    CGImageRelease(bitmapContext);

    // return the image
    return theImage;
}
```

Now you just need few lines of code. I put stuff in my viewController `viewDidLoad` method because it's faster but you can use it also in your custom `UIView` with the `layoutSubviews` method in example.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // Create the mask image you need calling the previous function
    UIImage *mask = MTDContextCreateRoundedMask( self.view.bounds, 50.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    // Create a new layer that will work as a mask
    CALayer *layerMask = [CALayer layer];
    layerMask.frame = self.view.bounds;       
    // Put the mask image as content of the layer
    layerMask.contents = (id)mask.CGImage;       
    // set the mask layer as mask of the view layer
    self.view.layer.mask = layerMask;              

    // Add a backaground color just to check if it works
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    // Add a test view to verify the correct mask clipping
    UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0 )];
    testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:testView];
    [testView release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

#### Solution 2

This solution is a bit more "dirty". Essentially you could create a mask layer with the rounded corner you need (all corners). Then you should increase the height of the mask layer by the value of the corner radius. In this way the bottom rounded corners are hidden and you can only see the upper rounded corner. I put the code just in the `viewDidLoad` method because it's faster but you can use it also in your custom `UIView` with the `layoutSubviews` method in example.

```
  

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // set the radius
    CGFloat radius = 50.0;
    // set the mask frame, and increase the height by the 
    // corner radius to hide bottom corners
    CGRect maskFrame = self.view.bounds;
    maskFrame.size.height += radius;
    // create the mask layer
    CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
    maskLayer.cornerRadius = radius;
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    maskLayer.frame = maskFrame;

    // set the mask
    self.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;

    // Add a backaground color just to check if it works
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    // Add a test view to verify the correct mask clipping
    UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0 )];
    testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:testView];
    [testView release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Hope this helps. Ciao!

Comment: Finally worked! Thanks so much! What is the advantage of one over the other?

Comment: Anyway even the CAShapeLayer solution is perfect. You can draw the CGPath using the UIBezierPath (that needs 3.2+) or just with the CGPath methods (CGPathMoveToPoint, CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint etc.)

Comment: How do I get the mask to autoresize after rotation from portrait to landscape?

Comment: Don't forget to add layer.masksToBounds = YES

Comment: how can do make it to round the top and bottom right corners only?

Comment: Solution 2 is more elegant for me, no image context needed, thanks!

Answer (score 69):

Combing through the few answers & comments, I found out that using `UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect` and `CAShapeLayer` the simplest and most straight forward way. It might not be appropriate for very complex cases, but for occasional rounding of corners, it works fast and smoothly for me.

I had created a simplified helper that sets the appropriate corner in the mask:

```
-(void) setMaskTo:(UIView*)view byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners
{
    UIBezierPath* rounded = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds byRoundingCorners:corners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

    CAShapeLayer* shape = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    [shape setPath:rounded.CGPath];

    view.layer.mask = shape;
}
```

To use it, simply call with the appropriate UIRectCorner enum, e.g.:

```
[self setMaskTo:self.photoView byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerBottomLeft];
```

Please note that for me, I use it to round corners of photos in a grouped UITableViewCell, the 10.0 radius works fine for me, if need to just change the value as appropriate.

**EDIT:** just notice a previously answered very similarly as this one ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4936555/1434320)). You can still use this answer as a added convenience function if needed.

---

**EDIT:** Same code as UIView extension in Swift 3

```
extension UIView {
    func maskByRoundingCorners(_ masks:UIRectCorner, withRadii radii:CGSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)) {
        let rounded = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: masks, cornerRadii: radii)

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = rounded.cgPath

        self.layer.mask = shape
    }
}
```

To use it, simple call `maskByRoundingCorner` on any `UIView`:

```
view.maskByRoundingCorners([.topLeft, .bottomLeft])
```

Comment: Is this possible while still adding a border?

Comment: I had to put function call into DispatchQueue.main.async {} because only one corner got rounded...

Comment: @MaksimKniazev yes, this must be called from main (UI) thread. This rule  applies to any actions touching UI, they must be called from main thread or some weird things might happen.

Comment: only one corner seems to round. tried @MaksimKniazev solution didn't work either.

Comment: I have the same problem as @Gustavo_fringe, where the top right corner is not clipped/masked to bounds inside (resized) a xib view, not sure how to fix it yet.

Comment: @CyberMew i am just guessing here, it might be the case that your view had resized since you last called maskByroundingCorners, as this code uses the current bound of the view at the time you call it to setup the size of the mask, if your view was resized to a smaller size later, you might only see the top left of the view masked (since the top right side of the mask is out of bounds now). Try calling the above mask function again to resize the mask after you had resized your view.

Comment: @P.L. Yes the view was resized to be bigger, I had to call `self.setNeedsLayout()` and `self.layoutIfNeeded()` in order to update the the child view bounds (I'm also using autolayout) and then it gets the correct updated bound data.

Answer (score 57):

I couldn't fit this all in a comment to @lomanf's answer. So I'm adding it as an answer.

Like @lomanf said, you need to add a layer mask to prevent sublayers from drawing outside of your path's bounds. It's a lot easier to do now, though. As long as you're targeting iOS 3.2 or higher, you don't need to create an image with quartz and set it as the mask. You can simply create a `CAShapeLayer` with a `UIBezierPath` and use that as the mask.

Also, when using layer masks, make sure that the layer you're masking is not part of any layer hierarchy when you add the mask. Otherwise the behavior is undefined. If your view is already in the hierarchy, you need to remove it from its superview, mask it, then put it back where it was.

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath *roundedPath = 
  [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:maskLayer.bounds
                        byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft |
                                          UIRectCornerBottomRight
                              cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(16.f, 16.f)];    
maskLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
maskLayer.path = [roundedPath CGPath];

//Don't add masks to layers already in the hierarchy!
UIView *superview = [self.view superview];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
self.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
[superview addSubview:self.view];
```

Due to the way Core Animation rendering works, masking is a relatively slow operation. Each mask requires an extra rendering pass. So use masks sparingly.

One of the best parts of this approach is that you no longer need to create a custom `UIView` and override `drawRect:`. This should make your code simpler, and maybe even faster.

Comment: Seems promising, but the view fails to appear. Any ideas why?

Comment: You're using the maskLayer.bounds to size the UIBezierPath but the value of the bounds is CGRectZero. You need to add a second line of code (immediatly after the CAShapeLayer initialization) like maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;

Comment: Yes, you're right. I extracted that code from another example where the shape layer already existed. Sorry about that.

Comment: It works perfectl! Adding maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds, as stated above, make is work. Otherwise the views don't show.

Comment: +1 This works quite well. In fact I think I prefer this method to lomanf's #2 solution. This method easily allows you to added arcs to opposite corners (eg: Top Right + Bottom Left), and it's certainly shorter than lomanf's first solution. Great code Nathan!

Answer (score 30):

I've taken Nathan's example and created a category on `UIView` to allow one to adhere to DRY principles. Without further ado:

### UIView+Roundify.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (Roundify)

-(void)addRoundedCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners withRadii:(CGSize)radii;
-(CALayer*)maskForRoundedCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners withRadii:(CGSize)radii;

@end
```

### UIView+Roundify.m

```
#import "UIView+Roundify.h"

@implementation UIView (Roundify)

-(void)addRoundedCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners withRadii:(CGSize)radii {
    CALayer *tMaskLayer = [self maskForRoundedCorners:corners withRadii:radii];
    self.layer.mask = tMaskLayer;
}

-(CALayer*)maskForRoundedCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners withRadii:(CGSize)radii {
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;

    UIBezierPath *roundedPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:
        maskLayer.bounds byRoundingCorners:corners cornerRadii:radii];
    maskLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    maskLayer.path = [roundedPath CGPath];

    return maskLayer;
}

@end
```

To call:

```
[myView addRoundedCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight
                withRadii:CGSizeMake(20.0f, 20.0f)];
```

Comment: Dont forget to import <QuartzCore/QuatzCore.h> in the .m file and also add QuartzCore.framework to project

Comment: +1 Great stuff, one question though, what is the purpose of removing / readding the view to it's superview?

Comment: @eladleb: The basic code here was from Nathan, I simply optimized it a bit. From the research I've done, I can't find a valid reason to remove the view before applying the layer mask. Therefore, I believe it's safe to omit that code.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer - I agree, then I'd vote for removing it, this actually changes the view z-order and can create more issues..

Comment: Solved the issue I was having with adding rounded corners to a TableView: I added a header, rounded toop corners and added a footer with rounded bottom corners. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

To expand a little on P.L's answer I rewrote the method like so as it wasn't rounding certain objects such as `UIButton` correctly

```
- (void)setMaskTo:(id)sender byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners withCornerRadii:(CGSize)radii
{
    // UIButton requires this
    [sender layer].cornerRadius = 0.0;

    UIBezierPath *shapePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:[sender bounds]
                                                byRoundingCorners:corners
                                                cornerRadii:radii];

    CAShapeLayer *newCornerLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    newCornerLayer.frame = [sender bounds];
    newCornerLayer.path = shapePath.CGPath;
    [sender layer].mask = newCornerLayer;
}
```

And call it by

```
[self setMaskTo:self.continueButton byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft|UIRectCornerBottomRight withCornerRadii:CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0)];
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to do it in Swift you could use an extension of a `UIView`. By doing so, all subclasses will be able to use the following method:

```
import QuartzCore

extension UIView {
    func roundCorner(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath
        layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
self.anImageView.roundCorner(.topRight, radius: 10)
```

Answer (score 4):

Extending the accepted answer, let us add backward compatibility to it. Prior to iOS 11, view.layer.maskedCorners is not available. So we can do like this

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    myView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner,.layerMaxXMinYCorner]
} else {
    myView.maskByRoundingCorners([.topLeft, .topRight])
}

extension UIView{
    func maskByRoundingCorners(_ masks:UIRectCorner, withRadii radii:CGSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)) {
        let rounded = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: masks, cornerRadii: radii)

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = rounded.cgPath

        self.layer.mask = shape
    }
}
```

We have written maskByRoundingCorners as an UIView extension so that it improves code reuse.

Credits to @SachinVsSachin and @P.L :) I have combined their codes to make it better.

Answer (score 2):

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(5, 5, self.bounds.size.width-10, self.bounds.size.height-10)
                                               byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(12.0, 12.0)];
```

change **"AllCorners"** according to your need.

Comment: so do you have to do this in the UIView or can this be done in the UIViewController?  What do you do with the UIBezierPath once you have made it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

All the solutions provided achieves the goal. But, `UIConstraints` can blow this up sometimes.

> For example, the bottom corners needs to be rounded. If height or
>   bottom spacing constraint are set to the UIView that needs to be rounded, the
>   code snippets that rounds the corners needs to be moved to
>   `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

**Highlighting:**

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath
    bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundedView.bounds byRoundingCorners:
    (UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(16.0, 16.0)];
```

The code snippet above will only round the top right corner if this code set in `viewDidLoad`. Because `roundedView.bounds` is going to change after the constraints updates the `UIView`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a mask and set it on the view's layer

Comment: How would I do that? I'm sort of shaky as far as the lower level view management goes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264083/rounded-uiview-using-calayers-only-some-corners-how might help you

Comment: Glad to see my answer is still helping people!

Answer (score 1):

Starting with your code, you might go with something like the snippet below.

I'm not sure if this is the sort of result you're after. Worth noting, too, that if/when the system calls drawRect: again, asking for only part of the rect to be redrawn, this is going to behave very strangely. [Nevan's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264083/rounded-uiview-using-calayers-only-some-corners-how), noted above, might be a better way to go.

```
 // make sure the view's background is set to [UIColor clearColor]
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat radius = 10.0;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2);
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI); // rotate so image appears right way up
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -rect.size.width/2, -rect.size.height/2);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y);
    CGContextAddArc(context, rect.origin.x + radius, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - radius, radius, M_PI, M_PI / 2, 1);
    CGContextAddArc(context, rect.origin.x + rect.size.width - radius, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - radius, radius, M_PI / 2, 0.0f, 1);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y);
    CGContextClip(context); 

    // now do your drawing, e.g. draw an image
    CGImageRef anImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"] CGImage];
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, anImage);    
}
```

Comment: I worked out a view with rounded corners, but I cant make it clip any of its subviews. If I place a view with square corners at the edge of my view, it still covers up the rounded corners of its superview. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Because clipping in `-drawRect:` only affects the view you're drawing. Its subviews draw independently after your drawing completes.

Answer (score 1):

Bezier path is the anwer, if you need additional code this one worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13163693/936957

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:_backgroundImageView.bounds 
                                 byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) 
                                       cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
_backgroundImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
[maskLayer release];
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly hacky, but relatively simple (no subclassing, masking, etc) way to this is to have two UIViews. Both with `clipToBounds = YES`.  Set rounded corners on the child view, then position it within the parent view so the corners you want straight are cropped.

```
UIView* parent = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,100)];
parent.clipsToBounds = YES;

UIView* child = [[UIView alloc] new];
child.clipsToBounds = YES;
child.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
child.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
child.frame = CGRectOffset(parent.bounds, +4, -4);


[parent addSubView:child];
```

Doesn't support the case where you want two diagonally opposite corners rounded.

Answer (score 1):

UIBezierPath solution.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [super drawRect:rect];

    //Create shape which we will draw. 
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(2, 
                                  2, 
                                  rect.size.width - 4,
                                  rect.size.height - 4);

    //Create BezierPath with round corners
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rectangle 
                                                   byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight 
                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

    //Set path width
    [maskPath setLineWidth:2];

    //Set color
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

    //Draw BezierPath to see it
    [maskPath stroke];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can only work if some things are set correctly:

1. clipsToBounds must be set to YES
2. opaque has to be NO
3. backgroundColor should be "clearColor" (i am not fully sure on this)
4. contentMode has to be "UIContentModeRedraw" as drawRect is not called often if it's not
5. [super drawRect:rect] has to be called after the CGContextClip
6. Your view may not contain arbitrary subviews (not sure on this)
7. Be sure to set "needsDisplay:" at least once to trigger your drawrect

Answer (score 0):

I realize that you're trying to round the top two corners of a UITableView, but for some reason I've found that the best solution is to use:

```
self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

Programmatically it should round all four corners, but for some reason it only rounds the top two. **Please see the screenshot below to see the effect of the code I've written above.

I hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: If it's not rounding all corners of the `UITableView` then there must be code elsewhere that is making the `UITableView` not have rounded corners on the bottom, or maybe even a `UIView` or `UILabel` that is covering the bottom part of the `UITableView`.

Answer (score -1):

You probably have to clip to bounds. Add the line

```
self.clipsToBounds = YES
```

somewhere in the code to set that property.