# iOS: Mask a UIImage using UIBezierPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage

I am trying to mask an image so that I can give it only two rounded corners.  With the code that I have it just adds the mask in white over the image, but doesn't seem to apply it.  What  do I need to do different to mask the image corners?

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath *roundedPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:maskLayer.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(16.f, 16.f)];    
maskLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
maskLayer.path = [roundedPath CGPath];

// Add mask
self.imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Round two corners in UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview/4936555#4936555)

As mentioned in the above linked question, you probably need to remove the view from the heirarchy before applying its mask.

```
[self.imageView removeFromSuperview];
self.imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
[self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
```

Also, your `maskLayer` has no `bounds`. You need to set it to the `frame` (or `bounds`) of the view you're trying to mask.

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = self.imageView.frame;
```

Comment: Please read Apple's documentation. I would start with [`UIImage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and also [`CGImage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000956-Reference-DontLinkElementID_1), which is the underlying image object inside a `UIImage`. You'll see that in `CGImage` there are functions to create an image using a mask, and then a `UIImage` constructor which takes your new `CGImage` as the image.