# Get UIBezierpath from masking an UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, masking, uibezierpath

How can I get `UIBezierpath` from `UIImage` like this..

[image]

I do not want full square path, Just want that path as shown in red border from UIImage..

I had gone through [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071815/ios-mask-a-uiimage-using-uibezierpath) and [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776747/masking-a-uiimage) but can't got success..

I had done following code to get masking path..

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = imgView.frame;
UIBezierPath *roundedPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:maskLayer.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(50.f, 50.f)];
```

Basically I want to get `UIBezierpath` that follows the shape of alphabets like A,B.. etc.

Please tell me is this possible or not to get this type of path??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Did you solve the issue? It seems there is still no answer to your question on stackoverflow... :o(

Answer (score 0):

For other users looking for answers, an alternative approach can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252237/uibezierpath-from-image) (Using SVG as a source image file and PocketSVG to convert to paths)

Answer (score -5):

Try this code:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation 
animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
pathAnimation.duration = 15.0;
pathAnimation.repeatCount = 1;
CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, x+15, y);
CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, 20, 10, 100, 330);
pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
CGPathRelease(curvedPath);
Yourimage.center=CGPointMake(x, y);
[Yourimage.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"moveTheSquare"];
```

Comment: Also check this tutorial ..i think its solve your problem.. http://blog.devedup.com/index.php/2010/03/03/iphone-animate-an-object-along-a-path/

Comment: This answer isn't related to the question asked at all. They asked how to obtain a UIBezierPath that could draw that shape, not an animation about a path.