# iPhone - Top left and right rounded corner for main application UIView issue

Tags: iphone, uiview, rounded-corners

I am using the following code to achieve the top right and left corner for my main UIView:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.view.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
[maskLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
self.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

But after that, all subviews like UIButtons contained in the UIView stop working. I think this could be a no brainer, but I just couldn't get the solution after much of the googling work.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers.

Comment: Here try this. I believe this person had a similar goal.


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071815/ios-mask-a-uiimage-using-uibezierpath or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview/4936555#4936555