# How to set cornerRadius for only top-left and top-right corner of a UIView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, cornerradius

Is there a way to set `cornerRadius` for only top-left and top-right corner of a `UIView`?

I tried the following, but it end up not seeing the view anymore.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:frame byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0)];
layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
view.layer.mask = layer;
```

Comment: After your edit, three things to fix: (1) the rounded path should be based on `view.bounds`, not `frame`, (2) the layer should be a `CAShapeLayer`, not `CALayer`; (3) set the layer's `path`, not `shadowPath`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2264083/429427) & [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5826698/429427).

Comment: Use the Bezier curve algorithm, to create curves on a CGPath. I'm pretty sure it's part of CoreGraphics. If not, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve has some great definitions and animations.

Comment: https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2018/02/how-to-set-roundcorner-radius-on-view.html

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396485/6246128

Comment: It's much easier on iOS 11 and above: https://johncodeos.com/how-to-round-only-specific-corners-to-a-uiview-in-ios-using-swift/

Comment: iOS 11 - Interface Builder only solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58626264

Answer (score 371, accepted):

Pay attention to the fact that if you have layout constraints attached to it, you must refresh this as follows in your UIView subclass:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 3.0)
}
```

If you don't do that it won't show up.

---

And to round corners, use the extension:

```
extension UIView {
   func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

---

---

**Additional view controller case**: Whether you can't or wouldn't want to subclass a view, you can still round a view. Do it from its view controller by overriding the `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` function, as follows:

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {
    /// The view to round the top-left and top-right hand corners
    let theView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 200))
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }()
    
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        view.addSubview(theView)
    }
    
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        // Call the roundCorners() func right there.
        theView.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 30)
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to do this after the view has appeared

Comment: if anyone faces the same dummy issue I did - if you're writing within ViewController, don't forget 

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        roundCorners()
    }

Comment: What if there is no subclass? Only an outlet to uiview.

Comment: In that case, you would like to override the view controller func viewWillLayoutSubviews() { super.viewWillLayoutSubviews() theView.roundCorners() }. Let me add this to the answer.

Comment: I use the 1st solution but its not working properly on ipad

Comment: borderColor and borderWidth not effect in ios 10 when use corner [.topLeft, .topRight]. https://github.com/phucdth12a/Images/blob/master/Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20-%20iPhone%205s%20-%202020-07-16%20at%2010.17.33.png

Comment: UIBezierPath works with fix size view, but create problem when view size change with auto layout constrains

Comment: It has saved me time (quick rounding of a fixed view), and cost me time (it breaks layout constraints unexpectedly). This way is causing glitches when animating the rounded view in certain cases (e.g. using animation with spring damping based).

Comment: Huge respect, Saved my hours, was missing viewWillLayoutSubviews, Thanks

Answer (score 565):

I am not sure why your solution did not work but the following code is working for me. Create a bezier mask and apply it to your view. In my code below I was rounding the bottom corners of the `_backgroundView` with a radius of 3 pixels. `self` is a custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath
    bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.backgroundImageView.bounds
    byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight)
    cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20, 20)
];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

self.backgroundImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Swift 2.0 version with some improvements:

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:viewToRound.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.TopRight, .BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

maskLayer.path = path.CGPath
viewToRound.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Swift 3.0 version:

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:viewToRound.bounds,
                        byRoundingCorners:[.topRight, .bottomLeft],
                        cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height:  20))

let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
viewToRound.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Swift extension [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35621736/308315)

Comment: try in textfield. success in left, failure in right

Comment: @RainerLiao i had the same issue, i did all this on the `viewDidLoad` method, move it to `viewDidAppear` and it worked.

Comment: how can I set this to work for any device. this only works fine for the `simulator` size int the storyboard. `ex: if the simulator size is 6s it works fine for 6s, but  not of others.` how can I overcome this.

Comment: Little syntax error in Swift 3 version: `path.CGPath` should be `path.cgPath`

Comment: @RainerLiao if you don't want it to flick as the view appears, change it to `viewWillAppear` instead. This also works.

Comment: Please note that masks are quite CPU-consuming.

Comment: not working for bottom. i.e. bottomLeft & bottomRight

Comment: don't forget to add  `viewToRound.layoutIfNeeded()`  Thanks

Comment: It's a [UIView property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622580-bounds)

Comment: @YunusNedimMehel this is working well But how can I use it in my view class in IBDesignable for changing the Edge corners in story board ?

Comment: Glad to hear. Sadly, I don't think you can do this on IB since this is an operation on the `.layer`.

Comment: You can expose `IBDesignable` properties on `UIView` subclasses who's getters and/or setters return/change properties of the view's backing layer. I keep an extension to `UIView` around that exposes a `borderColor` property that's a `UIColor`, for example. The getter returns the border color of the backing Layer (converted from a `CGColor` to a `UIColor`) and the setter takes a `UIColor` as input and sets the layer's border `CGColor`.

Answer (score 456):

And finally… there is [CACornerMask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cacornermask) in iOS11!
With `CACornerMask` it can be done pretty easy:

```
let view = UIView()
view.clipsToBounds = true
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner] // Top right corner, Top left corner respectively
```

Comment: this definitely works best. we always had issues with the other solutions when rounding the edges of dynamically sizing tableview cells.

Comment: what will do for older version?                                                                                                                       self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner,.layerMaxXMinYCorner]

Comment: @SHEBIN, try solutions from the other answers on this page

Comment: The other answers don't work when rotating the device, this code works for rotation and allows you to round certain corners, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Do not needed to set "view.clipsToBounds = true". Else it can have some side-effects on Shadow(if you have applied shadows as well)

Comment: This should be the top answer. It is the most direct and relevant answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Let's get this in top place

Comment: CACornerMask extension constants so humans can understand: https://gist.github.com/derekleerock/19a767c528b53ffa381a51c49f220595

Answer (score 287):

Here is a **Swift** version of @JohnnyRockex answer

```
extension UIView {

    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
         let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
         let mask = CAShapeLayer()
         mask.path = path.cgPath
         self.layer.mask = mask
    }

}
```

---

```
view.roundCorners([.topLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 10)
```

## Note

If you're using **Auto Layout**, you'll need to subclass your `UIView` and call `roundCorners` in the view's `layoutSubviews` for optimal effect.

```
class View: UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.roundCorners([.topLeft, .bottomLeft], radius: 10)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great extension. However: `.TopRight` and `.BottomRight` don't seem to work for me.

Comment: When doesnt those edges work? When you use only one of those edges or both or all edges? Because I havent ran into this problem.

Comment: on *Swift 2*:
`view.roundCorners([.TopLeft , .BottomLeft], radius: 10)`

Comment: This is a beautiful solution, but I can't seem to round any other corner but .TopLeft. Could this be due to AutoLayout or something? I don't know where to look, hehe.

Comment: Can't edit my comment but I was calling the function in the wrong function. Calling it in an

Comment: It's not working on the Right, because your view's bounds is not yet well defined with autolayout... I'm currently facing the same issue.

Comment: @dosdos Subclass that view and in layoutSubviews round the corners of self.

Comment: just to make it clear, like what Arbitur said: `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {viewToRound.roundCorners([.TopLeft, .TopRight], radius: BUTTON_RADIUS)}`

Comment: If you are in a UIView, use  `override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        // Round the bottom-left and top-right corners
        self.label.roundCorners([.BottomLeft, .TopRight], radius: CORNER_RADIUS)`
    }

Comment: If you use auto layout, and have not the reference to the view want to round, you can call `.layoutIfNeeded()`, then this method.

Comment: issue => That's work perfectly! Except that my view is resizing when Im using your function :( Any ideas??

Comment: not working for bottom. i.e. bottomLeft & bottomRight

Comment: I'm on Swift 4, use Auto-Layout, and I get a blank screen lol (view is invisible)

Comment: Calling `layoutIfNeeded()` did the trick. Just a note, if you want shadow on your view, shadow won't appear.

Comment: @Arbitur in swift 4 this is resizing the view and making it shorter. Any idea why? In `override func awakeFromNib()` I call `self.scheduledView.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 3.0)` then layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: @u.gen as I've stated in my answer. Place the code inside layoutSubViews instead.

Comment: awesome small solution. both topLeft and topRight are working.

Comment: It wont work if you are the view inside a table view. And also during screen rotation.

Answer (score 103):

Swift code example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35621736/308315

---

Not directly. You will have to:

1. Create a `CAShapeLayer`
2. Set its `path` to be a `CGPathRef` based on `view.bounds` but with only two rounded corners (probably by using [`+[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIBezierPath/bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:))
3. Set your `view.layer.mask` to be the `CAShapeLayer`

Comment: Be warned this will hurt performance if you do it on more than just a couple of views...

Comment: @jjxtra So what's the best way to do it without much performance loss? I want to show it in UITableViewCell.

Comment: @xi.lin from what I remember setting **layer.shouldRasterize == YES** improves speed 5 times or so. But the docs say it only works if you work with non-transparent cells. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 68):

Here is a short method implemented like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *openInMaps = [UIButton new];
    [openInMaps setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 135, 114, 70)];
    openInMaps = (UIButton *)[self roundCornersOnView:openInMaps onTopLeft:NO topRight:NO bottomLeft:YES bottomRight:NO radius:5.0];
}

- (UIView *)roundCornersOnView:(UIView *)view onTopLeft:(BOOL)tl topRight:(BOOL)tr bottomLeft:(BOOL)bl bottomRight:(BOOL)br radius:(float)radius {

    if (tl || tr || bl || br) {
        UIRectCorner corner = 0;
        if (tl) {corner = corner | UIRectCornerTopLeft;}
        if (tr) {corner = corner | UIRectCornerTopRight;}
        if (bl) {corner = corner | UIRectCornerBottomLeft;}
        if (br) {corner = corner | UIRectCornerBottomRight;}

        UIView *roundedView = view;
        UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundedView.bounds byRoundingCorners:corner cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        maskLayer.frame = roundedView.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        roundedView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
        return roundedView;
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: What about setting color ?      maskLayer.borderWidth = 10;
        maskLayer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
its not working for me sir.

Comment: @kiran a mask doesn't have a colour, you could add a second CAShapeLayer if you want to have a border

Answer (score 59):

It can workes Swift 5.x also, follow my complete answers.
In Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1

In **iOS 11** this single line is enough:

```
detailsSubView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]//Set your view here
```

See the complete code:

```
//In viewDidLoad
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        detailsSubView.clipsToBounds = false
        detailsSubView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        detailsSubView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
} else {
      //For lower versions
}
```

But for lower versions

```
let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
    rectShape.bounds = detailsSubView.frame
    rectShape.position = detailsSubView.center
    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: detailsSubView.bounds,    byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft , .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).cgPath
    detailsSubView.layer.mask = rectShape
```

**Complete code is.**

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    detailsSubView.clipsToBounds = false
    detailsSubView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    detailsSubView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
} else {
    let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
    rectShape.bounds = detailsSubView.frame
    rectShape.position = detailsSubView.center
    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: detailsSubView.bounds,    byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft , .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).cgPath
    detailsSubView.layer.mask = rectShape
}
```

If you are using AutoResizing in storyboard write this code in **viewDidLayoutSubviews()**.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        detailsSubView.clipsToBounds = false
        detailsSubView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        detailsSubView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    } else {
        let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
        rectShape.bounds = detailsSubView.frame
        rectShape.position = detailsSubView.center
        rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: detailsSubView.bounds,    byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft , .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).cgPath
        detailsSubView.layer.mask = rectShape
    }
}
```

Comment: Any solution for ios 9?

Comment: @jay let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
    rectShape.bounds = detailsSubView.frame
    rectShape.position = detailsSubView.center
    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: detailsSubView.bounds,    byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft , .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).cgPath
    detailsSubView.layer.mask = rectShape This code can work for iOS 9

Comment: Not working for ios 9. Its there is no border on corner part.

Comment: @jay I don't have iOS 9 os phone, but I checked in iOS 9 simulator. It's working...How & Where you checked. Can you suggest for me to check in iOS 9

Comment: i checked in simulator.. here is out put https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wXu1Ooetx1QTsX7cwCmQDs0nPvsfA1MrYsSINUi64Hk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: ` detailsSubView.clipsToBounds = false`  should be true right ?

Answer (score 40):

There is a super simple way of doing it.  I found it on [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/calayer/how-to-round-only-specific-corners-using-maskedcorners).

```
view.clipsToBounds = true
view.layer.cornerRadius = 24
view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
```

It uses the stock `cornerRadius` property on the `CALayer` of a view.  You just need to define the corners.  `layerMinXMinYCorner` is top left `layerMaxXMinYCorner` is top right.

Comment: I like this answer, short and concise.

Answer (score 36):

This would be the simplest answer:

```
yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
yourView.layer.masksToBounds = true
yourView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
```

Comment: tag that it is the solution for iOS 11 or above

Answer (score 30):

**Swift 4 Swift 5** easy way in 1 line

Usage:

```
//MARK:- Corner Radius of only two side of UIViews
self.roundCorners(view: yourview, corners: [.bottomLeft, .topRight], radius: 12.0)
```

Function:

```
//MARK:- Corner Radius of only two side of UIViews
func roundCorners(view :UIView, corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat){
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        view.layer.mask = mask
}
```

**In Objective-C**

Usage:

`[self.verticalSeparatorView roundCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight radius:10.0];`

Function used in a Category (only one corner):

```
-(void)roundCorners: (UIRectCorner) corners radius:(CGFloat)radius {
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:corners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
        CAShapeLayer *mask = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        mask.path = path.CGPath;
        self.layer.mask = mask;
    }
```

Comment: Only remember that the corners of your view are not calculated until the viewDidLayoutSubviews is done so you should call roundCorners func inside it

Comment: first add corner radius and then add shadow

Comment: @JirsonTavera thanks for the tip mate, it was making me crazy, almost took me an hour to find your comment here!

Comment: this solution causing shadows applied to the layer not to appear

Answer (score 29):

**iOS 11 , Swift 4**
And you can try this code:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
   element.clipsToBounds = true
   element.layer.cornerRadius = CORNER_RADIUS
   element.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
} else {
   // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

And you can using this in table view cell.

Comment: that's the right answer for today's coding. bye bye to mask layer.

Comment: This must be the best answer!

Answer (score 18):

My solution for rounding specific corners of UIView and UITextFiels in swift is to use

> .layer.cornerRadius

and

> layer.maskedCorners

of actual UIView or UITextFields.

**Example:**

```
fileprivate func inputTextFieldStyle() {
        inputTextField.layer.masksToBounds = true
        inputTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        inputTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        inputTextField.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner,.layerMaxXMinYCorner]
        inputTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }
```

And by using

> .layerMaxXMaxYCorner

and

> .layerMaxXMinYCorner

, I can specify top right and bottom right corner of the UITextField to be rounded.

**You can see the result here:**

[image]

Comment: Perfect for border and specific corners combination 

Comment: perfect solution

Answer (score 17):

Emma: `.TopRight` and `.BottomRight` are not working for you perhaps because the call to `view.roundCorners` is done BEFORE final `view bounds` are calculated. Note that the `Bezier Path` derives from the view bounds at the time it is called. For example, if auto layout will narrow the view, the round corners on the right side might be outside the view.
Try to call it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, where the view's bound is final.

Comment: Thank you. For me, what solved the issue was moving the call to the implementation given by "Arbitur" from viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear to viewDidAppear. I could do so since my control is initially set to hidden.

Comment: You are right. It will create issue with autolayout and you have done good job.

Answer (score 17):

Try this code,

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds byRoundingCorners:( UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;

view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4**

```
extension UIView {

    func roundTop(radius:CGFloat = 5){
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }

    func roundBottom(radius:CGFloat = 5){
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved my day in my case I had to make the table view rounded for particular cells

Comment: Perfect ans according my requirement. I used all the answer, nothing worked for me, but your answer helped me and solved my problem.

Answer (score 12):

Simple extension

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        if #available(iOS 11, *) {
            self.clipsToBounds = true
            self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
            var masked = CACornerMask()
            if corners.contains(.topLeft) { masked.insert(.layerMinXMinYCorner) }
            if corners.contains(.topRight) { masked.insert(.layerMaxXMinYCorner) }
            if corners.contains(.bottomLeft) { masked.insert(.layerMinXMaxYCorner) }
            if corners.contains(.bottomRight) { masked.insert(.layerMaxXMaxYCorner) }
            self.layer.maskedCorners = masked
        }
        else {
            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
            let mask = CAShapeLayer()
            mask.path = path.cgPath
            layer.mask = mask
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
view.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 12)
```

Answer (score 9):

Use this extension, it'll cover everything.

```
extension UIView {

   func roundTopCorners(radius: CGFloat = 10) {
    
       self.clipsToBounds = true
       self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
       if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
           self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
       } else {
           self.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: radius)
       }
   }

   func roundBottomCorners(radius: CGFloat = 10) {
    
       self.clipsToBounds = true
       self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
       if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
           self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
       } else {
           self.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: radius)
       }
   }

   private func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:-

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            
    self.yourView.roundTopCorners()
}
```

> Note:- I'll recommend you to don't put this code inside **viewDidLayoutSubviews()**, because whenever view updates, you'll get call inside it. So use **viewDidAppear()**, it'll work like a charm.

Comment: @SourabhSharma glad it helped :)

Answer (score 7):

Here is best way **Swift 5**:

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {

func roundCorners(radius: CGFloat = 10, corners: UIRectCorner = .allCorners) {
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            var arr: CACornerMask = []
            
            let allCorners: [UIRectCorner] = [.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight, .allCorners]
            
            for corn in allCorners {
                if(corners.contains(corn)){
                    switch corn {
                    case .topLeft:
                        arr.insert(.layerMinXMinYCorner)
                    case .topRight:
                        arr.insert(.layerMaxXMinYCorner)
                    case .bottomLeft:
                        arr.insert(.layerMinXMaxYCorner)
                    case .bottomRight:
                        arr.insert(.layerMaxXMaxYCorner)
                    case .allCorners:
                        arr.insert(.layerMinXMinYCorner)
                        arr.insert(.layerMaxXMinYCorner)
                        arr.insert(.layerMinXMaxYCorner)
                        arr.insert(.layerMaxXMaxYCorner)
                    default: break
                    }
                }
            }
            self.layer.maskedCorners = arr
        } else {
            self.roundCornersBezierPath(corners: corners, radius: radius)
        }
    }
    
    private func roundCornersBezierPath(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A way to do this programmatically would be to create a `UIView` over the top part of the `UIView` that has the rounded corners. Or you could hide the top underneath something.

Comment: Its a very ugly solution :P

Answer (score 6):

```
    // Create the path (with only the top-left corner rounded)
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds 
                           byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) 
                           cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(7.0, 7.0)];

// Create the shape layer and set its path
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = cell.stripBlackImnageView.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath; 
// Set the newly created shapelayer as the mask for the image view's layer
view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to make a mask with a rounded corner layer.

```
CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,maskWidth ,maskHeight);
maskLayer.contents = (__bridge id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"maskImageWithRoundedCorners.png"] CGImage];

aUIView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

And don't forget to:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Answer (score 4):

All of the answers already given are really good and valid (especially Yunus idea of using the `mask` property).

However I needed something a little more complex because my layer could often change sizes which mean I needed to call that masking logic every time and this was a little bit annoying.

I used swift `extensions` and computed properties to build a real `cornerRadii` property which takes care of auto updating the mask when layer is layed out.

This was achieved using [Peter Steinberg](https://twitter.com/steipete) great [Aspects](https://github.com/steipete/Aspects) library for swizzling.

Full code is here:

```
extension CALayer {
  // This will hold the keys for the runtime property associations
  private struct AssociationKey {
    static var CornerRect:Int8 = 1    // for the UIRectCorner argument
    static var CornerRadius:Int8 = 2  // for the radius argument
  }

  // new computed property on CALayer
  // You send the corners you want to round (ex. [.TopLeft, .BottomLeft])
  // and the radius at which you want the corners to be round
  var cornerRadii:(corners: UIRectCorner, radius:CGFloat) {
    get {
      let number = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociationKey.CornerRect)  as? NSNumber ?? 0
      let radius = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociationKey.CornerRadius)  as? NSNumber ?? 0
      return (corners: UIRectCorner(rawValue: number.unsignedLongValue), radius: CGFloat(radius.floatValue))
    }
    set (v) {
      let radius = v.radius
      let closure:((Void)->Void) = {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: v.corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.CGPath
        self.mask = mask
      }
      let block: @convention(block) Void -> Void = closure
      let objectBlock = unsafeBitCast(block, AnyObject.self)
      objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociationKey.CornerRect, NSNumber(unsignedLong: v.corners.rawValue), .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
      objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociationKey.CornerRadius, NSNumber(float: Float(v.radius)), .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
      do { try aspect_hookSelector("layoutSublayers", withOptions: .PositionAfter, usingBlock: objectBlock) }
      catch _ { }
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote a simple [blog post](http://www.dispatchasync.com/blog/partial-corner-radii/) explaining this.

Answer (score 3):

A lovely extension to reuse Yunus Nedim Mehel solution

**Swift 2.3**

```
extension UIView {
func roundCornersWithLayerMask(cornerRadii: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                            byRoundingCorners: corners,
                            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadii, height: cornerRadii))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.CGPath
    layer.mask = maskLayer
} }
```

**Usage**

```
let view = UIView()
view.roundCornersWithLayerMask(10,[.TopLeft,.TopRight])
```

Comment: Nice clean solution

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for an **interface builder only solution** there is one for **iOS 11 and higher**. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58626264

Answer (score 3):

Use this extension for set corner round and round border with round corners

use like this :

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

         myView.roundCornersWithBorder(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 8.0)
    
        myView.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 8.0)

        }



extension UIView {
   func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
    
    func roundCornersWithBorder(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)).cgPath
        
        layer.mask = maskLayer
        
        // Add border
        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        borderLayer.path = maskLayer.path // Reuse the Bezier path
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red:3/255, green:33/255, blue:70/255, alpha: 0.15).cgColor
        borderLayer.lineWidth = 2
        borderLayer.frame = bounds
        layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can set a corner radius for each corner of a button with **Xamarin in C#**:

```
var maskPath = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(MyButton.Bounds, UIRectCorner.BottomLeft | UIRectCorner.BottomRight,
    new CGSize(10.0, 10.0));
var maskLayer = new CAShapeLayer
{
    Frame = MyButton.Bounds,
    Path = maskPath.CGPath
};
MyButton.Layer.Mask = maskLayer;
```

Answer (score 2):

For `SwiftUI`

I found these solutions you can check from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56763282/3716103

I highly recommend the first one

**Option 1: Using Path + GeometryReader**

(more info on GeometryReader: https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-to-the-rescue/)

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {

        Text("Hello World!")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding(20)
            .background(RoundedCorners(color: .blue, tl: 0, tr: 30, bl: 30, br: 0))
    }
}
```

[image: give corner radius to text view using background]

`RoundedCorners`

```
struct RoundedCorners: View {

    var color: Color = .white

    var tl: CGFloat = 0.0
    var tr: CGFloat = 0.0
    var bl: CGFloat = 0.0
    var br: CGFloat = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Path { path in

                let w = geometry.size.width
                let h = geometry.size.height

                // Make sure we do not exceed the size of the rectangle
                let tr = min(min(self.tr, h/2), w/2)
                let tl = min(min(self.tl, h/2), w/2)
                let bl = min(min(self.bl, h/2), w/2)
                let br = min(min(self.br, h/2), w/2)

                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: w / 2.0, y: 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w - tr, y: 0))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: w - tr, y: tr), radius: tr, startAngle: Angle(degrees: -90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), clockwise: false)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: h - be))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: w - br, y: h - br), radius: br, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), clockwise: false)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bl, y: h))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: bl, y: h - bl), radius: bl, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 180), clockwise: false)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: tl))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: tl, y: tl), radius: tl, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 180), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 270), clockwise: false)
            }
            .fill(self.color)
        }
    }
}
```

`RoundedCorners_Previews`

```
struct RoundedCorners_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RoundedCorners(color: .pink, tl: 40, tr: 40, bl: 40, br: 40)
    }
}
```

[image: I give the corner radius to the top of view only]

Comment: How to make `RoundedCorners ` cover the bottom part and ignore the safe area ...

Answer (score 2):

### Make View TopLeft and TopRight CornerRadius ONLY

```
lazy var footerBackgroundView: UIView = {

    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .blue

    //Make Corners Radius TopLeft & Top Right
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner] 
    
    return view
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

After change bit of code @apinho In swift 4.3 working fine

```
extension UIView {
func roundCornersWithLayerMask(cornerRadii: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                            byRoundingCorners: corners,
                            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadii, height: cornerRadii))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
    layer.mask = maskLayer
  }
}
```

To use this function for you view

```
YourViewName. roundCornersWithLayerMask(cornerRadii: 20,corners: [.topLeft,.topRight])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version of [Stephane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41197790/4452289)'s answer.

```
import UIKit

    class RoundCornerView: UIView {
    var corners : UIRectCorner = [.topLeft,.topRight,.bottomLeft,.bottomRight]
        var roundCornerRadius : CGFloat = 0.0
        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            if corners.rawValue > 0 && roundCornerRadius > 0.0 {
                self.roundCorners(corners: corners, radius: roundCornerRadius)
            }
        }
        private func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
            let mask = CAShapeLayer()
            mask.path = path.cgPath
            layer.mask = mask
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.2, Create it via `@IBDesignable` like this:

```
@IBDesignable

class DesignableViewCustomCorner: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadious: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadious, height: cornerRadious))
            let mask = CAShapeLayer()
            mask.path = path.cgPath
            self.layer.mask = mask
        }
    }

}
```