# Creating a rounded-corner view

Tags: ios, objective-c

Good day!

Im trying to make my view (view in main view) make rounded corner. Im doing like this, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    currenView = [[UIView alloc] init]; 

    UIBezierPath *maskPath;
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:currenView.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(30.0, 30.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer.frame = currenView.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    currenView.layer.mask = maskLayer;


}
return self;
```

Comment: You can make it simply by using cornerRadius property of layer.

Answer (score 13):

Try something like this:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

for shadow:

```
view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
view.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
```

Make sure to import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: I've noticed you're not doing anything with the UIView you're allocating - currenView isn't going anywhere

Comment: After this line add view.clipsToBounds = YES

Comment: If this is a UIViewController, you need to assign it the view you're creating

Comment: @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *currenView; this view is IBOutlet.

Comment: So why are you instantiating a new one?

Comment: If the view is in IBOutlet then why are using "alloc , init"?

Comment: What's happening is this: You're assigning your controller an unrelated UIView which gets run over when viewDidLoad is called, that's when the storyboard/xib view is loaded. Chances are you're not even seeing the view you're creating in your init method.

Comment: ok, i got it, thank you. but even than it doesn't work (        UIBezierPath *maskPath;
        maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:currenView.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(30.0, 30.0)];
        
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        maskLayer.frame = currenView.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        currenView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
        
        currenView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
        currenView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

Comment: there is one more question: how to make shadow to this view?

Comment: Try the edited code. Keep in mind that you can't mask to bounds now.

Comment: i did it like in e.g. but the is no shadow

Comment: currenView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    currenView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    
    currenView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    currenView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
    currenView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    currenView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;

Comment: Remove the masksToBounds=YES line just to be sure, also make sure your view isn't set to clipsToBounds=YES

Comment: currenView.clipsToBounds = NO;
    currenView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
//    currenView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    
    currenView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    currenView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10.0f, 10.0f);
//    currenView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    currenView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
still there is no shadow yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code. Alloc init a view and send to this method to get corners rounded. You can optionally round any of the corners u want. Also give shadow stroke color.

```
-(void) setMaskTo:(UIView*)view byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners withColor:  (UIColor*) color
{
 UIBezierPath* rounded = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds  byRoundingCorners:corners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(9.0, 9.0)];

CAShapeLayer* shape = [[[CAShapeLayer alloc] init] autorelease];
[shape setPath:rounded.CGPath];
shape.strokeColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];

view.backgroundColor=color;
view.layer.mask = shape;
}
```

Call the method like this.

```
[self setMaskTo:ABCView byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners withColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Stavash's solution seems to be correct, I have used it several times. If you are looking for an alternative or insist on using masklayers, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13163693/936957

Answer (score 0):

Your view has no size. its w and h is 0. Try something like,

```
currentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0 200,200)];
```

and then apply

```
currentView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
currentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
currentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
```

Comment: view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
view.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;

if i do like this corners are rounded but there is no shadow. i think the problem is in 

view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

Comment: for shadow follow stavash's solution