# xcode UIImageView cornerRadius only one side

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image]

How can do this with `cornerRadius` and also I'm using `UIImageView`

Comment: Read this thread, maybe can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All You want to do is

1. First of all you should Add the  QuartzCore.framework through the
          Click your project-It is in left side of the Navigator Area
          Then click your project name of the TARGETS(It is below PROJECT-Left Side)
          Select Build Phases. If you select that you can see the 4 options.
          Then click Link Binary with Libraries. Once you click that just type Quartzcore. It shows that framework.Then just add it.
2. Import #import  in your relevent view controller.
3. Do the foollowing code in your .m part

   ```
    yourImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0; //For Example i give 5.0.So just give your required size.
    yourImage.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    yourImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor; //just give the color whatever you want
    yourImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
   ```

Once it works let me know.

Answer (score 0):

1. One master UIView without set Layer corner
2. add another UIImageView on it

[view addSubview:imageView];

3. set the layer corner on the UIImageView
4. set the frame for the UIImageView (e.g. imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20.f, weight, height);
5. This should work, if not, set the bounds for the UIView and clipToBounds = YES

If this works, please give me a good one as I am low in points XD

Answer (score 0):

To make the circular imageview use this following code in viewDidLoad. For clipped to bounds set it yes

```
self.MyImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.MyImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
 self.MyImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

To apply the border use this code in viewDidLoad

```
self.MyImageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f; 
self.MyImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```