# Curve-inside UIView top border

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I want to curve inside the top border of UIView like this,

[image]

I've tried many ways like UIBezierPath etc.

Help needed.

Comment: Try UIBezierPath again ;)

Comment: If UIBezierPath won't help than create image like above curve and set it as background of your view.

Comment: @Kampai : Actually i'm working with CAShapeLayer. There are multiple layers so i'm looking for some UIBezierPath solution.

Comment: Well i figured it out. Animate the whole view. During animation change the **self.view.origin.y**  to below. Now on completion set **self.view.origin.y** to its original position.

    NSInteger option = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut;
        orgRect = self.frame;
        CGRect tempRect = orgRect;
        tempRect.origin.y = tempRect.origin.y+20;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5 initialSpringVelocity:0.5 options:option animations:^{
            self.frame = tempRect;
        } completion:^(BOOL flag){
            self.frame = orgRect;
        }];

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `UIBezierPath`, Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13163693/3733561),

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:_backgroundImageView.bounds 
                             byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) 
                                   cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
_backgroundImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
[maskLayer release];
```

With this we can draw the rounded corners to any side of view.
But If you want to draw rounded edge, Better to take a background image to view.

Comment: Thanks but that answer is for round corners of UIView.

Comment: Agreed this is an incorrect answer and not what @Hxb was looking for