# ios setting the cornerRadius with trailing space , the corner radius not effect

Tags: ios, objective-c

I refer the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview) to build the UIView and UIButton corner radius.

But I found when I set the trailing space, the right part corner always not become  arc.

My code like below:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     self.btn = (UIButton*)[self roundCornerOnView:self.btn onTopLeft:YES topRight:YES bottomLeft:YES bottomRight:YES radius:5.0];
     self.myView = (UIView*)[self roundCornerOnView:self.myView onTopLeft:YES topRight:YES bottomLeft:YES bottomRight:YES radius:5.0];

 }

 -(UIView*) roundCornerOnView:(UIView*)view onTopLeft:(BOOL)tl topRight:(BOOL)tr bottomLeft:(BOOL)bl bottomRight:(BOOL)br radius:(float)radius
 {
     if( tl || tr || bl || br )
     {
         UIRectCorner corner = 0;
         if (tr)
         {
             corner = corner | UIRectCornerTopRight;
         }
         if (br)
         {
             corner = corner | UIRectCornerBottomRight;
         }


         if( tl )
         {
             corner = corner | UIRectCornerTopLeft;
         }
         if (bl)
         {
             corner = corner | UIRectCornerBottomLeft;
         }

         UIView *roundedView = view;
         UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundedView.bounds byRoundingCorners:corner cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
         CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
         maskLayer.frame = roundedView.bounds;
         maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
         roundedView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
         return roundedView;
     }
     else
     {
         return view;
     }

 }
```

My layout like below:

The button layout property:
[image]

The view layout property:
[image]

The right part always right angle like below.
[image]

How can I resolve this problem about the elements set the trailing space and with the corner radius?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should update the `frame` of `mask` layer inside `layoutSubviews` method of your views or inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of your view controller.

Because when you set mask layer's `frame`, the view has a different frame. After `autolayout` updates the frames and layouts subviews, the view has the correct `frame` value. And probably `autolayout` operates at `UIView` level, not on `CALayer` level. Therefore you should update mask layer's frame after layout phase.

Comment: thanks. Try to add in viewDidLayoutSubviews, it correct.

Comment: Glad it worked. For the sake of completeness, I suggest creating and adding mask layer inside viewDidLoad and then just updating its frame inside viewDidLayoutSubviews. Because as orientation changes, viewDidLayoutSubviews can be called again and you don't want to create and add mask layer twice.

Comment: But in the roundCornerOnView  method have roundedView.layer.mask = maskLayer; in there. They are called from viewdidload.  How to add mask layer inside viewDidLoad another? thanks.

Comment: basically you need to do this is the following
viewDidLoad: create and add mask layer
viewDidLayoutSubviews: access to mask layer and modify its frame

you can write new methods or change the current one for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.btn.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    self.myView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
}
```

You can also set these on IB via User Defined Runtime Attributes

Comment: because the OP does not want to round _all_ corners, maybe...?

Comment: `self.btn = (UIButton*)[self roundCornerOnView:self.btn onTopLeft:YES topRight:YES bottomLeft:YES bottomRight:YES radius:5.0];` seems like _all_ corners to me...

Comment: Yes, but he didn't mention about that. Maybe I should have asked first. Sorry