# Xcode: Topleft and topright corner radius not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to get a UIImageView to have its top corners rounded - and the top corners only.

Here's my code, that I based off the higher-voted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview) question:

`CouponViewController.m:`

```
@synthesize cv;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self loadXibWithName:@"CouponView"];
    cv = (CouponView *)self.view;
    cv.delegate = self;

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
    //[self displayLogoInNavBar];

    UIBezierPath *maskPath;
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cv.couponImage.bounds
                                     byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                           cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(15.0, 15.0)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer.frame = cv.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    cv.couponImage.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

The only thing different there (besides the variables) is the absence of `[maskLayer release]`, which caused an ARC error, and doesn't seem to help when said error is fixed, anyway.

There's also a `CouponView.m`, but that contains the `IBActions` and an `awakeFromNib`, that doesn't seem to do anything - I tried putting the following test code there:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.couponImage.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;
    self.couponPerforated.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"coupon_perforation_191"];
}
```

And finally, here's the `CouponView.xib` itself:

[image]

When it loads, the image is still a square.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Try change this line: maskLayer.frame = cv.bounds; to maskLayer.frame = cv.couponImage.bounds;

Comment: @Greg That worked, albeit it somehow resized my image to half, in `viewDidLoad`. Putting it in `viewDidAppear` did the trick, although the image visibly changes from a square to rounded top edges.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. After long time search it helps me.

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self setMaskTo:viewDistance byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight];
}

- (void)setMaskTo:(UIView*)view byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners
{
    UIBezierPath *rounded = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds
                                                  byRoundingCorners:corners
                                                        cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20.0, 20.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *shape = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    shape.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [shape setPath:rounded.CGPath];
    view.layer.mask = shape;
}
```