# how to change only left radius of UIbutton in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, ios9

Question :
How to change only left side radius of ui button??

Problem :
i have a 3 uibutton in my view.
and i want to change only left side radious of uibutton
here is my code

```
 btnsetting.layer.cornerRadius = 5
btnsaved.layer.cornerRadius = 5
btnall.layer.cornerRadius = 5
```

but its give radius to both side..

What i want to do:
[image: i want this kind of uibutton]

Comment: Why dont you use a segmented control? otherwise you should use background images for your buttons. You cannot give corner radius to single side

Comment: its work for me thanks@Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score -1):

You will have to:

- Create a `CAShapeLayer`
- Set its path to be a CGPathRef based on view.bounds but with only two rounded corners (probably by using `+[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:])`
- Set your `view.layer.mask` to be the `CAShapeLayer`

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167334/2303865

Comment: this is a verbatim copy/paste from http://stackoverflow.com/a/10167334/2303865

Comment: yes added credit link