# How to get rounded corners only on bottom of the blurview with clear color on iOS?

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, rounded-corners, cashapelayer, uivisualeffectview

I'm placing the blurview in a UITableViewCell. So the cell's background color is set to clear color. But I want specific corners to be rounded as well.

I came across [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview) for getting rounded corners.

1. Create a CAShapeLayer.
2. Create a UIBezierPath with specific corners and cornerRadii.
3. Apply it to the CAShapeLayer and add as a mask of the target view's layer.

But this works only when the view has a background color. I just want the specific corners rounded with clear color.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this to make corner, tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true

Comment: @ChandanPrajapati Thanks for your suggestion. But it will round all of the corners. But I want only specific corners (say bottomLeft & bottomRight) to be rounded.

Comment: Follow this link [try link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview)

Comment: @ChandanPrajapati Thanks once again. I've tried that solution. But when I do it on the UItableviewCell the blur effect I've added is gone. I want that blur effect as well as the specific rounded corners like the notifications on the lock screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.viewOutlet.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
self.viewOutlet.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

[image]