# My corner radius is applying to only one corner

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Hi I'm using this extension [how to set cornerRadius for only top-left and top-right corner of a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview/13163693#13163693) to apply rounder corners to my UIViews, however after the update to swift 3.0 the extension stopped working for UIViews that appear on top of other views.

Comment: And it's the .topRight corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this line right before all of your `...layer.cornerRadius =` lines in your controllers:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, activate 'Clip to Bounds' in the Storyboard