# How to make progressview with on side cornor radius

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar, uiprogressview

How to set progressview one side corner radius.

Please find the attachment the resultant progressView.
[YLProgressView](https://github.com/yannickl/YLProgressBar/blob/master/README.md)

Below is my ProgressView code.

```
cell.categoryImageView.backgroundColor = [categoryColorArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.categoryImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[categoryImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

cell.progressView.indicatorTextDisplayMode = MHProgressBarIndicatorTextDisplayModeProgress;
cell.progressView.type                     = MHProgressBarTypeFlat;
cell.progressView.behavior                 = MHProgressBarBehaviorIndeterminate;
cell.progressView.stripesOrientation       = MHProgressBarStripesOrientationVertical;

UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.progressView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopRight |  UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame =   cell.progressView.bounds;
maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
cell.progressView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

[image]

Your feedback is highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview

Comment: progressView  its a view

Answer (score 0):

Try this for corner radius for your progress view:

```
UIBezierPath *progressViewPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.progressView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20, 0)];
CAShapeLayer *progressViewLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
progressViewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
progressViewLayer.path  = progressViewPath.CGPath;
cell.progressView.layer.mask = progressViewLayer;
```