# make only bottom left corner in tableview cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a problem. 
I want to make the view about the corner like this but I don't know how to do this:

[i want to make this corner view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV33Y.png)

I also followed this Stackoverflow question [question url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview).

```
extension UIView {
func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)).cgPath
layer.mask = mask
}
```

so I use corner function in layoutsubview

```
//var labelContent:UILabel

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    labelContent.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomLeft,.topLeft,.topRight], radius: 10)


}
```

it work but when i scroll up ,the cell view is disappear.
so, i use second function.
but it doesnt work, too

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell: ChatContentTableViewCell = ChatContentTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

    let maskPathTop = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))
    let shapeLayerTop = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayerTop.frame = cell.labelContent.bounds
    shapeLayerTop.path = maskPathTop.cgPath
}
```

update: i follow Mr. Hedgehog suggestion:
when i scroll up , the cell view disappear.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let cell = cell as? ChatContentTableViewCell else { return }

    let maskPathTop = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.contentView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))
    let shapeLayerTop = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayerTop.frame = cell.contentView.bounds
    shapeLayerTop.path = maskPathTop.cgPath
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second solution does not work because you are instantiating new instance of the cell instead of using the one provided by callback.

Change the first line to:

`guard let cell = cell as? ChatContentTableViewCell else { return }`

And then try. The second thing - are you sure you need to update the label`s corners and not the content view's that holds it?

Comment: when i scroll up the cell view is disappear too.

Comment: i use content view ,nothing happen