# Adding circular corner only on the top of the view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to achieve a view like this:
[image]

I've been trying using this piece of code 
`let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .topLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 140, height: 140))`

But all I got is something like this:

[image]

I've already tried to change `width` and `height` values, but the view seems to not change at all, so how do I draw a view which contains that rounded top as shown in the first image?

Thanks for suggesting a solution , but as I said above, I can set the corners rounded, I can't make only the top of my view circular, so this is a different question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set cornerRadius for only top-left and top-right corner of a UIView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview)

Comment: Actually it's not duplicated because I can make the corners rounded, what I want is to make them circular, just like I show in the first image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [a circular `UIBezierPath`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibezierpath/1624358-init) and adjusting its radius. This way, as long as your view doesn't extend indefinitely (like a `UIScrollView` could), you'll get the effect you want.

```
let radiusRatio = CGFloat(2 / 3)

let screenRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenHeight = screenRect.height
let screenWidth = screenRect.width
let circleCenter = CGPoint(x: screenWidth / 2, y: screenHeight / ((1/radiusRatio) * 2))

let maskPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: circleCenter,
                            radius: screenHeight * radiusRatio,
                            startAngle: 0, 
                            endAngle: CGFloat.pi,
                            clockwise: true)
```

The `radiusRatio` variable controls how much of the screen's height the circle's radius takes,  or in other terms, how down low your circle's center is. Adjusting the `radiusRatio` should eventually give you what you want.

Comment: I tried to add the code above to my view: `let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = circularView.bounds
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath circularView.layer.mask = maskLayer`, but nothing happened, I think I might be doing something wrong.