# How to add selected corner radius and shadow for UIView in swift

Tags: swift, shadow, cornerradius

Can someone please help me with this question in iOS Swift. I have an UI view with drop shadow effect. I need corner radius for 3 corners except for one corner. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Dharani

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Stack Overflow has so many answers for every question. you gotta search in a right way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use extension on UIView:

Here is a sample I created on Playgrounds:

```
let view = UIView()

extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(_ corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
// customize where you want your roundCorners on your UIView
view.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomRight], radius: 10)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview