# Swift Left Side only rounded button with border

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

[image]

How can i get this kind of dropdown ?

I'm using button. Able to get rounded corners but border on left to be round and straight on right is a problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set cornerRadius for only top-left and top-right corner of a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview)

Comment: Hello @RakeshaShastri - Please see image now and suggest solution

Comment: If you go through the link, you'll be able to get the solution yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can follow below steps to achieve the layout of Dropdown you want.

1.Use UITableView for dropdown.

2.Create a UITableViewCell.

3.Add Rounded Corner to the UIView on one side.

```
let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
rectShape.bounds = self.roundedView.frame
rectShape.position = self.roundedView.center
rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.roundedView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft , .topLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).cgPath

 self.roundedView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
//Here I'm masking the textView's layer with rectShape layer
 self.roundedView.layer.mask = rectShape
```

4. Add border to roundedView.