# Control height of iOS 13 modal presentation

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, segue

I would like to display a view controller (with a date picker and a toolbar in it) with a overall height of 260 pt. I have set the preferred explicit size in the storyboard editor, however I believe that only affects the popover size. I have tried all the various combinations of segue/preferred presentation types, and they all display the date picker full screen. Indeed, the functionality works, however the pop up take up the whole screen.

[image: interface builder screenshot]

This is what it looks like:

[image: simulator screenshot]

Comment: You need a custom transition.

Comment: put a view with 260px in the controller, with bottom constraints (no top ones) and present it :) it will work just fine

Comment: @rmaddy if you have hits or links on where to find guidance on the custom transition, it would help me out a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- create your ChildViewController
- add a Vertical Stack View, put everything you need inside (or any other container view)
- calculate that container's view's height
- change height of ViewController's View to that
- set corner radius of View

```swift
import UIKit

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        // distance to top introduced in iOS 13 for modal controllers
        // they're now "cards"
        let TOP_CARD_DISTANCE: CGFloat = 40.0

        // calculate height of everything inside that stackview
        var height: CGFloat = 0.0
        for v in self.stackView.subviews {
            height = height + v.frame.size.height
        }

        // change size of Viewcontroller's view to that height
        self.view.frame.size.height = height
        // reposition the view (if not it will be near the top)
        self.view.frame.origin.y = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - height - TOP_CARD_DISTANCE
        // apply corner radius only to top corners
        self.view.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 10.0)
        super.updateViewConstraints()
    }
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/41197790/225503
extension UIView {
   func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Code Sample [here](https://github.com/dfreniche/iOS13ModalHeight)