# How make UIVIEW corner radius in specific side and different?

Tags: ios, uiview, swift5, cornerradius, xcode11.2.1

I have attached the image. I want create corner radius of `UIView`. Please look image https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkUuO.png

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
let redBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
redBox.backgroundColor = .red
redBox.layer.cornerRadius = 25
redBox.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
```

Looks like a similar question asked here: [How to set cornerRadius for only top-left and top-right corner of a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview)