# Is to possible to round only one corner from Toolbar?

Tags: objective-c

Just want to round one corner instead of 4. Is it possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounded UIView using CALayers - only some corners - How?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264083/rounded-uiview-using-calayers-only-some-corners-how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just googled 'round one corner objective-c' and I found these

[Round two corners in UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview)

[Rounded UIView using CALayers - only some corners - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264083/rounded-uiview-using-calayers-only-some-corners-how)

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/95917-adding-rounded-corners-only-top-uitableview.html

I didn't try anything, but I'm sure you can work something out with these.