# UIView rounded corners

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have to round only upper corners of `UIView`. I'm trying to use the following code:

```
UIBezierPath *maskEmailPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.emailandAccessView.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
CAShapeLayer *maskEmailLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskEmailLayer.frame = self.myview.bounds;
maskEmailLayer.path = maskEmailPath.CGPath;
self.myview.layer.mask = maskEmailLayer;
```

but it hides everything in that view. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: try not setting the frame of the mask layer to be the bounds of your view

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make specific corners of UIView round](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067897/make-specific-corners-of-uiview-round)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it.

```
  CALayer *capa = self.view.layer;
  CGRect bounds = capa.bounds;
  UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds
                                                 byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                                       cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];

  CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
  maskLayer.frame = bounds;
  maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

  [capa addSublayer:maskLayer];
  capa.mask = maskLayer;
```