# clipsToBounds and masksToBounds in grouped UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uikit, quartz-core, cglayer

I'm trying to get my `UITextView`'s corners to be masked by the rounded corners of the grouped `UITableViewCell` that contains it.  Here's a screenshot of the cell as it currently stands

[image: UITextView inside grouped UITableViewCell]

Here's some of the code I'm using to try to prevent the corners from overlapping my cells borders.  I tried both

```
cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;  //tried this as a test, still doesn't work
detailTextView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[cell.contentView addSubview:detailTextView];
```

and

```
cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
detailTextView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[cell addSubview:detailTextView];
```

This is obviously not working, what am I missing?

Comment: have you tried `cell.clipsToBounds = YES;`?

Comment: Yes but that's not what I need anyway.  `clipsToBounds` means that the cell would hide parts of it's layer that are outside it's parents.  I want the `UITextView` to hide the parts of its layer outside its parent (the cells contentView/the cell itself)

Comment: the bounds of your contentView are bigger than the bounds of your cell   so clipping the contentview will not solve your problem - you have to clip to the cell

Comment: Are you using storyboards? I think you can just check `Clip Subviews` on the cell but I am not sure how to do this in code.

Comment: Pfitz, masking at the cell or cell.contentView level makes no difference.  Neither does adding the detailTextView as a subview of one or other.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that the rounded corners in the grouped UITableViewCell aren't actually bounds but just bitmaps that make the cell look pretty.

Comment: Or at least they aren't a value that you can access via the contentView and are part of some subview of contentView

Comment: A couple ideas - have you tried `cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;`?  I'm guessing you have, but I don't see it in the code anywhere.  You might have to create a mask layer based on `cell.backgroundView`.  Be careful with that approach though, as it will probably reduce your frame rate, particularly while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can't mask the corners this way.  The cell's `backgroundView` is an image for a grouped `UITableView` so there's no sense of masking.

A possible solution to the problem would be to round the corners yourself.  This is a little tricky since you only want to round the top corners of the top cell and the bottom corners of the bottom cell.  Fortunately, @lomanf posted a great solution to rounding arbitrary corners here: [Round two corners in UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview/4930166#4930166). Using his `MTDContextCreateRoundedMask` method, we can achieve our goal.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Other cell instantiation

    // First cell in section
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [self roundTopOrBottomCornersOfCell:cell top:YES];       
    }
    // Last cell in section
    else if (indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section-1) {
        [self roundTopOrBottomCornersOfCell:cell top:NO];
    }
}

// Modified from the second part of @lomanf's Solution 1
- (void)roundTopOrBottomCornersOfCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell top:(BOOL)top {
        // Set constant radius
        CGFloat radius = 5.0;

        // Create the mask image you need calling @lomanf's function
        UIImage* mask;
        if (top) {
            mask = MTDContextCreateRoundedMask(self.view.bounds, radius, radius, 0.0, 0.0);
        }
        else {
            mask = MTDContextCreateRoundedMask(self.view.bounds, 0.0, 0.0, radius, radius);
        }

        // Create a new layer that will work as a mask
        CALayer* layerMask = [CALayer layer];            
        layerMask.frame = cell.bounds;

        // Put the mask image as content of the layer
        layerMask.contents = (id)mask.CGImage;

        // Set the mask layer as mask of the view layer
        cell.layer.mask = layerMask;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occurred to me

The difference is that i'm using the plain style and I'm trying to make every cell with rounded corner. Finally, i made it,here is my way:

1.
       put this code in your custom tableViewCell's awakeFromNib method

```
    [cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
```

2.
       set your custom TableViewCell's contentview's backGround color to white color,then set your tableView's backgroung color to clear color. That's all.