# UITableViewCell (grouped) subview in front of body

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I am designing a UITableView (grouped) with an image to the very left. My probem is that the grouped table view has rounded outer borders and the images overlap this round.

Have a look here: http://cl.ly/image/3q2t150g1s2z

How do I solve that?

Comment: Are you implementing heightForRowAtIndexPath method in your class?

Comment: Nope. They are the default 45px and my UIImageView is made with CGRect at a height of 43px from offset y=0.

Answer (score 0):

You can round the corners of the `UIImageView` via its layer property.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"something.jpg"]];
image.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
```

You can play with the corner radius value to match the corner of the grouped table view. Of course this will round all 4 corners of the image. I've never had the need to round only select corners, but if you have the need, [this question would probably help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview).

Comment: That could be a solution. But I was thinking that there might be an easier way? Like in HTML/CSS where you can specify the z-index, can't I define that the cell structure is above the content?

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact ordering of the `UIView` layers involved in a grouped table view, but you don't have direct access to any of them outside of the `UITableViewCell` you are creating. I am pretty sure the `UITableViewCell` is positioned above the background of the grouped table view and you would need the corner of the image to go behind this background, placing the image behind the cell background.

Comment: The `layer` property is probably read-only, but the `layer` is not immutable. You can change its `cornerRadius` property. There is a `setCornerRadius` method for this too (which is actually called in the above code when changing that property).

Answer (score 0):

1.easy way is that change image frame to round corner

2.or change cell's layer to rect corner then add layer to cell, this may need more action.

you can try this:
cell.layer.cornerRadius="shape you want"

sure use  framework in your app