# How can I set maskToBounds effect on CAShapeLayer(Rounded-Recr cornered UIView)?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, cashapelayer

`I want to make the glow effect spread outside of thisView.`

I used this code to make `Half-Rounded rect cornered UIVew`.

[Round two corners in UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview)

Here is my code.

```
+ (UIView *)makeUpperHalfRoundedView:(UIView *)view {
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = view.bounds;
    UIBezierPath *roundedPath =
    [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:maskLayer.bounds
                          byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight
                                cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8.f, 8.f)];
    maskLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    maskLayer.path = [roundedPath CGPath];
//    maskLayer.masksToBounds = NO;

    //Don't add masks to layers already in the hierarchy!
    UIView *superview = [view superview];
    [view removeFromSuperview];
    view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    [superview addSubview:view];

    return view;
}
```

And there are `two image buttons` in this view closed to the boundary. 
If a touch event happen on buttons, glow effect shows(`showsTouchWhenHighlighted`)

Before using this piece of code, I just used

```
thisView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
thisVIew.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

and glow effect spread outside of 'thisView'.

But after using CAShapeLayer in 'thisView' to masking half-roused rect, the glow effect are masked by boundary.

Comment: "Don't add masks to layers already in the hierarchy!" Who told you *that*???

Comment: comment just written on the code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is exactly how a mask is supposed to work. You are applying the mask to the layer of the superview. Let's call that view `superview` (just as in your code). Okay, so what will that do? It will mask `superview` and all its sublayers. *That includes its subviews.* Its subviews are actually its sublayers.

So, since the buttons are subviews of `superview`, they are masked like everything else inside `superview`.

If you don't want that to happen, don't make the buttons subviews of `superview`. They can sit on top of `superview` without being its subviews, for example.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. One idea came up to me. make two layers which has exactly same frame. one is `frontView` which contains buttons, another one is `backView` which is half-rounded rect UIView. Then I use code above to make `backView`, and move two buttons to frontView. How about this?

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking of. Or just move the two buttons out in front, and have them be subviews of `superview.superview` :)

Comment: I solved this problem with two separated views which are subviews of one superView. Your advice is good point. Thank you ;-)