# UIBezierPath does not draw rounded bottom corners

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, rounded-corners, uibezierpath

I am trying to make rounded corners for my views and fencing a strange problem.

I use the following code to make rounded corners for my view

```
bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:btnView.bounds
                                       byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners
                                             cornerRadii:radius];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer.frame = btnView.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
    btnView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

The problem is, it is not working for bottom corners. If I use `UIRectCornerBottomLeft` nothing happens, if I use `UIRectCornerAllCorners` only top corners are rounded.

EDIT: I dont use layer.cornerRadius because I just want to round bottom corners.

It turned out I do not have problem, if I remove `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` autoresizing mask from my view. But I would like to use autoresizing mask. Is it possible if yes how?

I have already tried setting autoresizingMask before and after setting the mask of the layer. No luck!

Comment: why dont you just use layer.cornerradius?

Comment: right @LithuT.V i post that answer before you post that comment :)

Comment: @ParasJoshi : Yeah i posted a comment and at the same time you put it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until I get an another answer, if it is possible to use autoresizingMask with `UIBezierPath`, I say **NO** and mark as correct answer.

I do not delete my question, because anybody can fence the same problem without knowing the reason.

Comment: just try your code in     
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // make round corner
});

Comment: any reason for this? I did that into viewDidLoad() and viewDidLayoutSubviews() but nowhere it worked. It worked when I applied dispatch_main... it seems weird. any reason for this?

Answer (score 12):

I have just had a similar problem that's taken hours to solve - the answer was very simple: move my code from viewDidLoad to viewDidLayoutSubviews: this is the first method called after autolayout has completed .... so I suspect I did have 4 rounded corners but somehow they were off the edge of the screen.

Comment: In rotation viewDidLayoutSubviews will not called and not good for autolayout.

Answer (score 1):

then instead of that use bellow code for rounded corners...

```
btnView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
```

just import `QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h` in your `.m` like bellow...

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

**UPDATE:**

For that you can use different `RoundingCorners` Properties of `UIBezierPath` lik bellow....

For Ex : `UIRectCornerBottomLeft`,`UIRectCornerBottomRight`,`UIRectCornerTopLeft`,`UIRectCornerTopRight` and `UIRectCornerAllCorners`.

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: btnView.bounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = btnView.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
btnView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
[btnView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: @Mert also see this link with many answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264083/rounded-uiview-using-calayers-only-some-corners-how

Comment: Yes, I know it and use it, but it does not work for bottom corners because of autoresizingMask.

Comment: @Mert see this answers same like ur problem.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
-(void)roundCorners:(UIRectCorner)corner radius:(float)radius
{   
    _cornerRadius = radius;
    _corner = corner;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    [super drawRect:rect];

    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:_corner cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(_cornerRadius, _cornerRadius)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

```swift
bezierPath.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.Round
```

Answer (score 0):

you can user `view.layer.cornerRadius` to set the rounded corners.

Edited: Use the following

```
 layer.mask = MTDContextCreateRoundedMask(layer.bounds, topleftRadius, topRightRadius, bottomLeftRadius,bottomRightRadius);
```

This is the supported method.

```
static inline UIImage* MTDContextCreateRoundedMask(CGRect rect, CGFloat radius_tl, CGFloat radius_tr, CGFloat radius_bl, CGFloat radius_br)
{
    CGContextRef context;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    context = CGBitmapContextCreate( NULL, rect.size.width, rect.size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast );

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    if ( context == NULL ) {
        return NULL;
    }


    CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX( rect ), midx = CGRectGetMidX( rect ), maxx = CGRectGetMaxX( rect );
    CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY( rect ), midy = CGRectGetMidY( rect ), maxy = CGRectGetMaxY( rect );

    CGContextBeginPath( context );
    CGContextSetGrayFillColor( context, 1.0, 0.0 );
    CGContextAddRect( context, rect );
    CGContextClosePath( context );
    CGContextDrawPath( context, kCGPathFill );

    CGContextSetGrayFillColor( context, 1.0, 1.0 );
    CGContextBeginPath( context );
    CGContextMoveToPoint( context, minx, midy );
    CGContextAddArcToPoint( context, minx, miny, midx, miny, radius_bl );
    CGContextAddArcToPoint( context, maxx, miny, maxx, midy, radius_br );
    CGContextAddArcToPoint( context, maxx, maxy, midx, maxy, radius_tr );
    CGContextAddArcToPoint( context, minx, maxy, minx, midy, radius_tl );
    CGContextClosePath( context );
    CGContextDrawPath( context, kCGPathFill );

    CGImageRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreateImage( context );
    CGContextRelease( context );

    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:bitmapContext];
    CGImageRelease(bitmapContext);

    return theImage.layer.mask;
}
```

Comment: I get "Implicit declaration of function MTDContextCreateRoundedMask is invalid". And I could not find any doc about the function is this a private API?

Comment: I get warning "Incompatible pointer types assigning to CALayer * from UIImage *" and if I run It crashes with bad access

Answer (score 0):

Had to change corners of view. did not work with bottom corners in viewDidLoad due to autoresizing. Had to move code to viewDidAppear.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
self.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;

self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the sucess and it really works. Try It.

```
CGRect frame = self.accountBackgroundImage2.frame;
frame.size.height = self.view.bounds.size.height;
UIBezierPath *path=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.accountBackgroundImage2.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft |UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(12.5, 12.5)];

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
shapeLayer.frame = self.accountBackgroundImage2.bounds;
shapeLayer.path  = path.CGPath;
_accountBackgroundImage2.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
self.accountBackgroundImage2.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Way

Execution in  " viewWillLayoutSubviews "

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
[self roundCornersOnView:self.buttonJoin onTopLeft:NO topRight:YES bottomLeft:YES bottomRight:NO radius:10.0];
}
```

Function

```
-(UIButton *)roundCornersOnView:(UIButton *)button onTopLeft:(BOOL)tl topRight:(BOOL)tr bottomLeft:(BOOL)bl bottomRight:(BOOL)br radius:(float)radius {

if (tl || tr || bl || br) {
    UIRectCorner corner = 0; //holds the corner
    //Determine which corner(s) should be changed
    if (tl) {
        corner = corner | UIRectCornerTopLeft;
    }
    if (tr) {
        corner = corner | UIRectCornerTopRight;
    }
    if (bl) {
        corner = corner | UIRectCornerBottomLeft;
    }
    if (br) {
        corner = corner | UIRectCornerBottomRight;
    }

    UIButton *roundedView = button;
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundedView.bounds byRoundingCorners:corner cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = roundedView.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    roundedView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    return roundedView;
} else {
    return button;
}
```

}