# Only one corner is getting rounded in UITextField/UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am using the following code to make UITextField's/UIView's Top corners rounded, but the problem is only left top corner is getting rounded. What I am doing wrong or is there any other way to do so.

```
- (void)roundCornersOnView:(UIView*)view onTopLeft:(BOOL)tl topRight:(BOOL)tr bottomLeft:(BOOL)bl bottomRight:(BOOL)br radius:(float)radius
{

    if (tl || tr || bl || br) {
        UIRectCorner corner = 0; //holds the corner
        //Determine which corner(s) should be changed
        if (tl) {
            corner = corner | UIRectCornerTopLeft;
        }
        if (tr) {
            corner = corner | UIRectCornerTopRight;
        }
        if (bl) {
            corner = corner | UIRectCornerBottomLeft;
        }
        if (br) {
            corner = corner | UIRectCornerBottomRight;
        }

        UIView* roundedView = view;
        UIBezierPath* maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundedView.bounds byRoundingCorners:corner cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
        CAShapeLayer* maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        maskLayer.frame = roundedView.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        roundedView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    }
}
```

Calling the above method

```
[self roundCornersOnView:textField onTopLeft:YES topRight:YES bottomLeft:NO bottomRight:NO radius:5.0];
```

[image: As u can see in the screen shot, I have applied the same code in it.]

Comment: check my answer i have edited

Comment: Shubham, your code is working fine for me. I changed all four corners without changing a single line of your code.

Comment: BTW: It's better to do such things in a category, eg like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14485362/849616. You create a category on UIView (or subclass) and just call your function. Your code is working perfectly (I did run it in xcode).

Comment: screenshot please...

Comment: @iphondroid :  I only want top corners to get rounded. Did you achieved that?

Comment: yes I did.. by simply passing YES for top two corners... I think @Vive also did.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is nothing wrong in the code. Some other view on the right side overlaps the textfield. This gives you a feeling that your right corner is not rounded. Check same thing by making all four corner as round and you will able to identify same.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot where i applied the same code. I crosschecked there is no other view overlapping the view.

Answer (score 0):

For single corner:

```
textField.roundCorners(corners: .topLeft, radius: 0.07 * textField.bounds.height)
```

For mutliple corner:

```
textField.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft], radius: 0.07 * textField.bounds.height)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
UItextField * textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:Frame];
textField.delegate = self;
[textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[textField.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
[textField.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
[textField.layer setCornerRadius:14.0f];
textField.placeholder = @"PlaceHolder";
[self.view textField];
```

Hope it helps.

Check this link

[how to set cornerRadius for only top-left and top-right corner of a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need only top corners of the textfield to get rounded not the bottom ones. Will this code fulfil the requirement.

Comment: The question is not how to do it but why is the code wrong. Your answer doesn't answer it.