# How can I design textfield or button like comboBox in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I'm trying to design such a button or a textfield, but exactly how can I do it? This is my textfield. I added an arrow to the right.

```
@IBOutlet weak var pickerTextField: UITextField!{
    
    didSet {
        pickerTextField.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        pickerTextField.setIcon(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "drop-down-arrow"))
    }
    
}

extension UITextField {
    func setIcon(_ image: UIImage) {
        let iconView = UIImageView(frame:
        CGRect(x: -40, y: 7, width: 15, height: 15))
        iconView.image = image
        
        let iconContainerView: UIView = UIView(frame:
        CGRect(x: -50, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        
        
        iconContainerView.addSubview(iconView)
        rightView = iconContainerView
        rightViewMode = .always
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I just added arrow to the right. I can change background color of container view. But then I need to round corners. Because its'a square so another problem is how can I just round  right corners.

Comment: For [only rounding the right corners](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/calayer/how-to-round-only-specific-corners-using-maskedcorners) you can do `yourRightView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]`

Comment: To have round corner this you can try out ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview/45434170#45434170

Comment: Are you also looking for the dropdown implementation

Comment: no just button design

Comment: @cemsezeroglu Why would you add the UIImageView inside another view? Whats wrong with setting the UIImageView as your rightView?