# How to curve UIVew only top corner and not whole view in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to curve UIView. I want to curve the radius of the top of UIView like this in the Image

[image]

As you can see the screenshot of my work view.

I am using code like this

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath
                          bezierPathWithRoundedRect:ViewSwapMyWork.bounds
                          byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight)
                          cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(70, 70)
                          ];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

maskLayer.frame = ViewSwapMyWork.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

ViewSwapMyWork.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: you want to only curve upper half of the view or full round shape ?

Comment: @HiteshSultaniya Only upper half of the view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you make a UIView with rounded top corners and square bottom corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499663/how-can-you-make-a-uiview-with-rounded-top-corners-and-square-bottom-corners)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First your view should have the same height and width means it should be square, then you can do like this,

```
[ViewSwapMyWork.layer setCornerRadius:ViewSwapMyWork.frame.size.width/2];
[ViewSwapMyWork.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: @Muju if your problem is solved then please accept the answer :)

Comment: This answer will curve all the corners and not just the top corners as requested

Comment: @simon_smiley Yes But I can hide below view.

Comment: @Muju "Yes But I can hide below view" classic :O