# How can I round just the bottom corners of a UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [UIView with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/uiview-with-rounded-corners)
>   [Round two corners in UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview)

I'm aware of means for rounding all four corners of a UIView, but how could I round only the bottom corners of a view?

Comment: Not a duplicate. How about you read the detail before giving a -1 ???

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to use `CALayer` masking. This question [Just two rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845211/just-two-rounded-corners) and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview/4930166#4930166) should get you started. If you run in to trouble, then you should take a look at this follow-up post: [Round two corners in UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview)

Answer (score 1):

You can draw in one CALayer filled rectangle with bottom rounded corners and than set it as mask to your:

```
[[view layer] setMask:calayerWithDrawedMaskingRect];
```