# Is there a way to have just one rounded corner on a UIButton?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

On a UIButton, I know how to create 4 rounded corners, and I know how to create 4 squared corners, but now what I need is a way to create a UIButton with 3 squared corners and 1 rounded corner.  Is there a way to do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You just need to modify the code slightly from the following posts:

[Just two rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845211/just-two-rounded-corners)

[Round two corners in UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview)

You can also hack this by rounding all corners of one UIView and then adding two other UIViews on top to "unround" the top two and left two corners, leaving just the lower right corner rounded.