# how to draw UIButton with tint color and rounder from single side only

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I wanna  draw a UIButton filled with a **red tint color** or some color else presented by rgb and **only the upper edges are rounded**.
some people answer me to get an image to do that but every time i want to change it i have to bring new image and replace it, I wanna ask can i do it from code without get an image.

Comment: Possible duplicates : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845211/just-two-rounded-corners

Comment: thank you @rdurand this was helpful next to ACB answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way. Only way to achieve this to create a segment control and keep only a single segment in that.

See [this post](http://charles.lescampeurs.org/2011/02/10/tint-color-uibutton-and-uibarbuttonitem) for detailed implementation,

**Update:**

If you want to round only two corners check [Round two corners in UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview) or [Just two rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845211/just-two-rounded-corners) as mentioned in rdurand's comment. Since segment control is a subview of `UIView`, this should work.

Comment: All corners are already rounded right? Check the image in http://charles.lescampeurs.org/2011/02/10/tint-color-uibutton-and-uibarbuttonitem. If you want to round only the two corners check the comment by rdurand on question.

Comment: Updated my answer with those links.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the rounded corners using NSBezierPath s `bezierPathWithRoundedRect:xRadius:yRadius:` method. And then draw over it with another bezier path. Or you could just define a custom bezier path using moveToPoint: lineToPoint: and curveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:

Take a look at this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html