# Corner radius just in particular corner

Tags: swift4, rounded-corners

I am working in Swift 4 and I am trying to make a button with just two of the four corners rounded (for some buttons the top-right and button right and for some the top-left and bottom-left corners).

I've search a lot and all that I've found is this: `myButton.layer.cornerRadius = newCornerRadiusInPixels;`. It works perfectly but it roundes all the corners at the same time.

is there a way to round just a particular corner?
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845211/just-two-rounded-corners/12491545#12491545

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Available in iOS 11 and up:

```
myButton.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner]  // or some other corner(s)
```

Comment: This is correct. Available variables for all 4 corners:
[.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
extension UIView {

    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
         let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
         let mask = CAShapeLayer()
         mask.path = path.cgPath
         self.layer.mask = mask
    }

}
```

---

```
view.roundCorners([.topLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 10)
```

Comment: thanks man, it did not work for me. I used exactly as shown and placed it in the view did load. Am I missing something?